# Search for specific Web Template in SharePoint Search

Tags: search, site-template, site-definition

Is it possible to construct a SharePoint Search Query for a specific web type (site definition / web template id) in the same manner as for lists?

I can easily search for my custom lists using `contentclass = 'STS_List_20001'` if my custom list has ID 20001.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

No, this is unfortunately not possible. The contentclass is always STS_Web and there is no crawled property available with the template id. But you could create your own list of sites with Metadata in a SharePoint list and search that.

Comment: Nice to see you in here Lars ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I caught your question a few days ago and it got me thinking about a solution to this problem I worked on some time ago. I got around to blogging it this week and thought it might help:
[Using HTML Meta Tags to add Information to SharePoint Search](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Daniel/archive/2009/12/07/using-html-meta-tags-to-add-information-to-sharepoint-search.aspx)